# "Cannot get / " Ghost blog hosting issue

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, ghost-blog

I want to install a ghost blog with my angular app. Angular app and ghost blogs are in separate directories which are "example_site" and "example_blog" respectively in the file system. My angular app is on "example.in" and I want ghost blogs to be accessible under "example.in/blogs".
I have used a proxy, Here is my apache server config

```
<virtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.in
        ServerAlias www.example.in
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ https://www.example.in$1
</virtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName example.in
        ServerAlias www.example.in
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example_site/dist/

        <Directory /var/www/html/example_site/dist/>
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteBase /
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteRule .* /index.html [L]
        </Directory>


        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass /blogs/ http://127.0.0.1:2368/
        ProxyPassReverse /blogs/ http://127.0.0.1:2368/


        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /var/www/html/example_site/cert/123.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/html/example_site/cert/example.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/html/example_site/cert/examplecrt


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my ghost config

```
{
  "url": "https://example.in/blogs",
  "server": {
    "port": 2368,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "database": {
    "client": "mysql",
    "connection": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "user": "admin",
      "password": "***",
      "database": "example_blogs_prod"
    }
  },
  "mail": {
    "transport": "Direct"
  },
  "logging": {
    "transports": [
      "file",
      "stdout"
    ]
  },
  "process": "systemd",
  "paths": {
    "contentPath": "/var/www/html/example_blogs/content"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution
I added **RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https**
and did some changes to the files, Here is the updated files
Here is my apache server config

```
<virtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.in
        ServerAlias www.example.in
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ https://www.example.in$1
</virtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName example.in
        ServerAlias www.example.in
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example_site/dist/

        <Directory /var/www/html/example_site/dist/>
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteRule .* /index.html [L]
        </Directory>

        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass /blogs http://localhost:2368/blogs
        ProxyPassReverse /blogs http://localhost:2368/blogs

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /var/www/html/example_site/cert/123.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/html/example_site/cert/example.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/html/example_site/cert/examplecrt


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the ghost config file

```
{
  "url": "https://example.in/blogs",
  "server": {
    "port": 2368,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "database": {
    "client": "mysql",
    "connection": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "user": "admin",
      "password": "***",
      "database": "example_blogs_prod"
    }
  },
  "mail": {
    "transport": "Direct"
  },
  "logging": {
    "transports": [
      "file",
      "stdout"
    ]
  },
  "process": "systemd",
  "paths": {
    "contentPath": "/var/www/html/example_blogs/content"
  }
}
```